# How can I animate the tracing a SVG rectangle using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, animation, svg

For a game I'm working on,

I would like to be able to draw a SVG rectangle; using a percentage value (50% would draw half the rectangle stroke).
I need to do this in Javascript since I'll update the value quite often.

```
<svg id="rectangle-timer" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <rect width="100%" height="100%"/>
</svg>
```

I saw quite nice JS libraries like [drawSVG](https://greensock.com/drawSVG) or [Vivus](https://maxwellito.github.io/vivus/), but it seems that they work with paths, not with basic shapes like rectangles.

Can anyone help ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason most libraries will use `path` elements is because of their inheritance from the `SVGGeometryElement` prototype, which gives you handy functions for computing the path length. So if we swap out this rectangle for a path like this:

```
<path d="M 0 0 L 1 0 L 1 1 L 0 1 z" />
```

We get exactly the same output, but its much more controllable. After that, we can just adjust the `strokeDasharray` value in the style to extend and remove some stroke. For this property we just need two values: initial dash size and initial empty space. So when our progress is 0, we want the first value to be 0 and the second to be the path length , and as we approach 1 we want the second value to 0 and the first one to increase to the path length.

```js
function update( amount ){
  
  const total = rect.getTotalLength();
  const filled = total * amount;
  const none = total - filled;
  
  rect.style.strokeDasharray = `${filled} ${none}`;
  
}

const rect = document.getElementById( 'rectangle' );
const input = document.getElementById( 'input' );

input.addEventListener( 'mousemove', event => update( input.value ));
update( input.value );
```

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <path d="M 20 20 L 180 20 L 180 180 L 20 180 z" id="rectangle" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>

<input id="input" type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" />
```

If you insist on using a `rect`, you could get a rectangle's path length by taking its width and height twice, which would look something like this:

```js
function update( amount ){
  
  const total = rect.width.baseVal.value * 2 + rect.height.baseVal.value * 2;
  const filled = total * amount;
  const none = total - filled;
  
  rect.style.strokeDasharray = `${filled} ${none}`;
  
}

const rect = document.getElementById( 'rectangle' );
const input = document.getElementById( 'input' );

input.addEventListener( 'mousemove', event => update( input.value ));
update( input.value );
```

```html
<svg width="200px" height="200px" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
    <rect x="20" y="20" width="160" height="160" id="rectangle" fill="none" stroke="black" stroke-width="10" />
</svg>

<input id="input" type="range" min="0" max="1" step=".01" />
```

In the long run, however, this would mean less versatility, so I would suggest switching to `path`.

Comment: thanks for your help.  Here's how I finally did it :     `updateQuestionTimerGui(percent){

        var el = $('#question-timer').get(0);
        
        if (el){
            var pathLen = el.getTotalLength();
            var adjustedLen = percent * pathLen / 100;
            el.setAttribute('stroke-dasharray', adjustedLen+' '+pathLen);
        }

    }`

Comment: @gordie personally, I would have kept the `0-1` range, as it means you need to do less back-converting, but yeah, that looks like it works!

Answer (score 3):

This is my solution: The SVG has `preserveAspectRatio ="none" style="width:100%;height:100vh;"` The total length of the path is `2*window.innerWidth + 2*window.innerHeight;` Both `stroke-dasharray` and `stroke-dashoffset` are igual to the total length of the path.

I'm using an input type="range" to animate the `stroke-dashoffset`.
In order to preserve the stroke width and avoid stretching I'm using `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

I hope this is what you need.

```js
function timer(){
let totalLength = 2*window.innerWidth + 2*window.innerHeight;
thePath.setAttributeNS(null, "style", `stroke-dashoffset:${totalLength * (1-range.value)}`)
}
timer()

range.addEventListener("input",timer);


setTimeout(function() {
  timer()
  addEventListener('resize', timer, false);
}, 15);
```

```css
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
#thePath {
  stroke-dasharray: calc(2 * 100vw + 2* 100vh);
  stroke-dashoffset: calc(2 * 100vw + 2* 100vh);
}
#rectangle-timer{background:#dfdfdf}
[type="range"] {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 20px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<svg id="rectangle-timer" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio ="none" style="width:100%;height:100vh;">

    <path id="thePath" d="M0,0L100,0 100,100 0,100 0,0" fill="none" stroke="skyBlue" stroke-width="25" vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke" />
</svg>

<input type="range" id="range" value=".5" min="0" max="1" step=".01"  />
```

Comment: Unfortunately, because of the stretching, this approach will result in a rectangle with stroke widths that are different depending on whether it is a horizontal edge of a vertical edge.

Comment: @PaulLeBeau It doesn't. I'm using `vector-effect="non-scaling-stroke"`

Comment: Yes. Missed that sorry.